# java ecc exception:invalid mac

Tags: java, encryption

We're using JDK 8,with bouncycastle 1.5.
We have two PC. Each PC can encrypt and decrypt corretly. But if one PC encrypt, and the other one decrypt it, there is an exception thrown:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Invalid MAC.
at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.ec.IESCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
at com.zhouxiang.cryption.bouncycastle.CryptionTest.main(CryptionTest.java:155)
```

Here is my decryption code:

```
File secKey = new File(ROOT_PATH+"pkcs8_key.key");
byte[] privateKeyB = readByte(secKey);
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyB);

KeyFactory privateFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ec",provider);
PrivateKey privateKey = privateFactory.generatePrivate(privateSpec);
Cipher privateCipher = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES/NONE/Nopadding", provider);
privateCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] encryptedFromFile = readByte(new File(ROOT_PATH+"test/real/testout.dat"));
byte[] decrypted = privateCipher.doFinal(encryptedFromFile);

FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(ROOT_PATH+"test/real/testout_de.txt"), decrypted);`
```

I've searched a lot for invalid mac but no answers.
Is it means ECC can only encrypt and decrypt on the same PC? Or is there anything wrong in it?

Comment: Well, same keys + same data + same crypto setup should give the same result .. so one of these are different on the two PC. Verify that you use the same key and the same data by printing it out in your code.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen yes，we're sure we're using the same key and same data.......and we search a lot for the 'invalid key',but still nothing...by the way,this key pair is generated by openssl on centos 6.5.

Comment: Why are you talking about 'invalid key' - your question is about a 'invalid mac' exception in the doFinal() call. Do a hexdump of the two byte arrays `privateKeyB ` and `encryptedFromFile` from both PC's. Are they **exactly* the same on both PC's? Prove they are the same from the programs point of view - as the error you describe indicates they are not.